# the loop - how to control whether wp or plug-in runs it

Tags: loop

I have a problem with the loop running on two instances with thecartpress plugin.  Im not great with php by any standards but can usually get things done, however with wordpress im fairly new.  Is there a way to have my plugin control the loop for just my catalog page and have wordpress ignore it?  i hope im not being to vague.

THIS IS ALL CODE FROM PAGE.PHP IN MY THEME

```
        <?php 
            global $projectTheme;

            get_header();

        ?>


        <?php get_template_part('theloop'); ?>

        <?php comments_template(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('navigation'); ?>

                    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

THIS IS THE ONLY HTML ON THE CATALOG PAGE CREATING THE DUPLICATION

```
                  [tcp_list id="all_products"]
```

That is shortcode from the tcp (thecartpress plugin)  Now this plugin is great, it gives you options for theme compatibility, asking how to display things in your catalog, and whether to let your theme control the loop, or use their configurable loop, however i have exhausted every bit on settings within their control panel and none of their settings effect this.  I believe anymore its something with their shortcode, which is done by using a shortcode generator they supply with the plugin.  I feel as though my theme runs this shortcode, and their plugin as well no matter how i set it, causing a double loop?

Comment: Are you looking to control the HTML output of the loop on a particular page? How exactly is the output for the page being generated? Is it via a custom template you're providing, or is it handled by the theme?

Comment: take a look here please http://dtowndiscgolf.com/wp/?page_id=96 you'll see the page "Catalogue" is repeating its posts twice.. so id like it to only display once, but i feel as if ,y theme and thecartpress plugin are each fighting for attention, but i just cant figure out where.  the HTML output doesnt show anything funny going on, other then the repetition

Comment: Thanks for the link! Now, could you paste 2 things in your question: 1. The PHP code for the **page.php** template in your theme, and 2. The HTML content (from the WordPress editor on the *Edit Page* screen) from the page in question? That will help us figure out what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Hey again, I have one more question - when you remove the shortcode from the HTML content, are *both* loops removed, or does one remain on the page? Basically, is the shortcode itself generating the 2 loops, or is it generating only 1 in addition to the "regular" loop?

Comment: hi andy, no when i remove the short code it does not do ANY loops at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my the loop.php file, i was executing a new loop using the wordpress parameters for the main loop, which caused a duplication with the plugin being used (thecartpress) which executes its own loop.  I was using:

```
       global $post, $query_string, $discTheme;
       query_posts($query_string);
```

in a sense, with thecartpresses own loop, I was duplicating the loop for this page.

With the bright eyes of my friend the sensei, a simple removal of:

```
       query_posts($query_string);
```

fixed my duplication issue.

Hope this makes sense and helps anyone else out there.